# Unique for attributes in two elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm building XML and XML schema for a chess game. There shouldn't be duplicates on position.

To solve that, I used unique, so this works for each element but not both together. For example, if I have position "66" for player black's pawn, rook, bishop, then it shows those are duplicated. However, if I put player white's pawn and player black's knight on position "66" together, it unique doesn't work.

Here's my schema code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- Type Definitions -->
  <xs:simpleType name="pieceSymbolType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="P|p|R|r|N|n|B|b|K|k|Q|q" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="pieceNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="pawn|rook|knight|bishop|king|queen" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="piecePositionRangeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="11" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="88" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="playerNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="BLACK|white" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="takenPieceType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="yes|no" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="myChess">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="player" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="pieces">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="piece" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="16">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="pieceNameType" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute name="position" type="piecePositionRangeType" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="pieceSymbolType"  use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="takenPiece" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="15">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="pieceNameType" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="pieceSymbolType"  use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="UniquePiecePosition">
                  <xs:selector xpath="piece" />
                  <xs:field xpath="@position" />
                </xs:unique>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="playerNameType"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to move your `xs:unique` so that it's in the context of `myChess` and then update the `xs:selector/@xpath`...

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- Type Definitions -->
    <xs:simpleType name="pieceSymbolType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="P|p|R|r|N|n|B|b|K|k|Q|q" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="pieceNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="pawn|rook|knight|bishop|king|queen" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="piecePositionRangeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="11" />
            <xs:maxInclusive value="88" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="playerNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="BLACK|white" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="takenPieceType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="yes|no" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="myChess">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="player" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="pieces">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="piece" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="16">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="pieceNameType" use="optional" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="position" type="piecePositionRangeType" use="required" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="pieceSymbolType"  use="required" />
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="takenPiece" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="15">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="pieceNameType" use="optional" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="pieceSymbolType"  use="required" />
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="playerNameType"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="UniquePiecePosition">
            <xs:selector xpath="player/pieces/piece" />
            <xs:field xpath="@position" />
        </xs:unique>                    
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```